# Calling constructor class with sets and gets sharedpreferences from an asyncTask (can't pass context)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, android-context, weak-references

I am getting and setting sharedPreferences in a Constructor class

```
private Context context;
public NewBusiness (Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    pref = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
public String getLogo() {
    return pref.getString("logo", logo);
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    editor.putString("logo", logo);
    editor.commit();
}
```

However I am calling this from a Async Task (which uses a WeakReference context, to prevent memory leaks)

```
private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;
public UploadBusiness(Context context) {
    contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    newBusiness = new NewBusiness(contextRef); //Can´t use WeakReference<Context>
    return "Upload successful";
}
```

Problem is that a weakreference context can't be passed as context

How do I call my constructor class with context without causing memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the get() method on the weak reference instance to get the actual object. Something like this:

```
private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;
public UploadBusiness(Context context) {
    contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context);
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    if(contextRef.get()!=null){
        newBusiness = new NewBusiness(contextRef.get());
    } 
    return "Upload successful";
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped...always better to do a null check when using the get method to ensure your context hasn't been destroyed yet. Updated the answer with the null check